# hist() not showing all columns

Tags: r, histogram

I'm importing a `df` and then running `hist()` on the `df`:

```
df <- read.table("https://leicester.figshare.com/ndownloader/files/23581310", sep = ",", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
hist(df)
```

but it doesn't show the histograms of all 124 columns - only a subset. I'm not sure why? How do I get a histogram of all the columns in a df? I want to be able to run `hist()` on the entire data frame because it also shows the number of values/missing values at the bottom of each histogram.

[image]

Comment: I would guess space constraints.. How many do get by using `skimr:skim(df)`?

Comment: @Pax I get all 124 but I'm not sure if it's because of space constraints because if I subset `df` to something like `df_subset <- df[1:20]` and run `hist(df_subset)`, it still doesn't give me all the columns.

Comment: @AllanCameron I don't think so, it's just base R `hist()`

Comment: @karuno if you just need the number of missing elements in each column, why not just do `colSums(sapply(df, is.na))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder how you could at all use `hist` in a data frame without `Vectorize`ing it. Best would be you use a different device such as the `png`.

```
png('foo.png', 2560, 1440)
par(mfrow=c(12, 11))
Vectorize(hist)(df)
dev.off()
```

[image]

### Update

We can get nice titles and labels with nobs and missings using `lapply` and a `misfun` for convenience.

```
misfun <- \(z) paste(
  paste(c('n', 'm'), table(factor(as.double(is.na(z)), levels=0:1)), sep=':'), 
  collapse=' ')

png('foo2.png', 2560, 1440)
par(mfrow=c(12, 11))
lapply(names(df), \(x) hist(df[[x]], main=x, xlab=misfun(df[x])))
dev.off()
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
df <- read.table("https://leicester.figshare.com/ndownloader/files/23581310", sep = ",", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: This is good but is it possible to change the title of each histogram to the column name and also include a caption in the bottom specifying the number of values vs missing values? Such that the format of each histogram looks like the one in my post.

Comment: @karuno Sure no problem using `lapply` and a `misfun` for convenience, see update.

Comment: Thank you! I get an error when trying to run the updated code: `Error: unexpected input in "misfun <- \"`

Comment: @karuno Update your R or use `function(x)` instead of `\(x)` ;)

Answer (score 1):

If all you are only looking for are the number of missing values in each column but don't really need the histograms, you can do:

```r
colSums(sapply(df, is.na))
```

If you need this as an image, then it will be much clearer to draw it with `text` rather than `hist`:

```r
df2 <- data.frame(col = paste(names(df), colSums(sapply(df, is.na)), 
                              sep = '\n \nMissing = '),
                  x = (seq(ncol(df)) - 1) %% 12, 
                  y = 12 - (seq(ncol(df)) - 1) %/% 12)
plot(df2$x, df2$y, type = 'n', xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n', xlab = '', ylab = '',
     bty = 'n')
text(df2$x, df2$y, label = df2$col, cex = 0.5)
```

[image]